# Django Model DateField to_python

Tags: python, django, validation, model, django-admin

I am working on Django 1.4, and I have a the following doubt. When parsing between dates on Django Admin, the format should be on the format "%Y-%m-%d". I just checked the code, and the django model DateField isn't using the settings to check the valid date for "to_python".

For exmaple, the only valid format right now is:

```
&fecha_inicio__lte=2012-06-10
```

But I also want that:

```
&fecha_inicio__lte=06/10/2012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this function to convert dates:

```
import re

def parse_slash_date(value):
    m = re.match(r'^(?P<day>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<month>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})$', value)
    if m:
        return '%s-%s-%s' % (
            m.group('year'), m.group('month'), m.group('day'))
```

Example:

```
In [4]: parse_slash_date('06/10/2012')
Out[4]: '2012-10-06'
```

You could also create a DateField that uses the parser:

```
class YourDateField(models.DateField):
    def get_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value):
        if value and '/' in value:
            value = parse_slash_date(value)
        return super(YourDateField, self).get_prep_lookup(
            lookup_type, value)
```

However, I was pretty sure that DateField was able to parse dates with slashes already... But I just read the code of django.utils.dateparse.parse_date and it doesn't.